# Add command (console command) in a Prestashop module 1.7.6

Tags: composer-php, prestashop-1.7, symfony-3.4

I'm developing a prestashop module (v. 1.7.6) and I'd like to add some command available from console.
The problem is that when I configure services and try to run

`bin/console mymodule:mycommand`

system returns **There are no commands defined in the "mymodule" namespace.**

Here my services.yml

```
services:

  mycommand_command:
    class: Mymodule\MycommandCommand
    tags:
      - { name: 'console.command' }
```

Here my composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Mymodule\\": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "src/Command/"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "prepend-autoloader": false
  },
  "type": "prestashop-module",
  "author": "<???>",
  "license": "<???>"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: add command class code to your question

Comment: I just face it again and... the module should be "installed" :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

To myself:

When you Google this question next time - check:

1. Command defined in config/services.yml
2. The module is installed
3. Composer autoloder dumped

Old version:

Make sure you dumped autoloader in Composer and added `protected static $defaultName = 'yourmodule:command';` to your command class and set the name any other way mentioned in Symfony docs.

I just faced the same issue a few days ago.

Comment: Thank you Serge P. I did it but it doesn't work. Can you shortly explain the steps you did please? Thank you

Comment: @Alreadynight Prestashop docs point you to Symfony docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container
basically in addition to files you posted you need to create command's class with `execute` method and `$defaultName` property.
Do you see your command in `php bin/console` output?

Comment: No, I don't see it.
I created the class (a simple class that just output a string "export done") with protected static $defaultName and method execute.

I followed the guide you mentioned but there's something wrong (probably in my composer.json). Thank you

Comment: My steps are: create the class that extends command, configure composer.json, configure services.yml in my module directory, run `composer dump-autoload -o --no-dev`. But I don't see my command when I run `php bin/console`. Thank you

Comment: in my case I had problem with Composer too. Since everything worked in Docker container and my IDE run Composer under container's root... there were permissions issues. I removed vendor dir and dumped again. I believe that's was the reason.

Comment: I mean basically there is autoload issue, so as a starting point I'd check if classes under my namespace ever loaded.

Comment: Did you add a require in your module.php file to load autoload.php? Thank you

Comment: Can you show me your composer.json please? Thank you

Comment: If I run `php bin/console debug:container` I see my command, but if I run `php bin/console mymodule:mycommand` the error is `There are no commands defined in the "mymodule" namespace`

Comment: I use ` "prepend-autoloader": true` for specific needs, so that's not the reason.

In console debug I see: `wwt.update_command       Wwt\Command\UpdateCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Where have you create your Command class ? `In src/Command/` ?

Comment: I set Gbstockimport as namespace and I use it i the composer.json. I tried to follow this example without success https://github.com/frederic-benoist/fbsample-console     Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To anyone is looking for this:

1. Follow the step on this link: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/commands/
2. Add composer.json IN THE ROOT OF YOUR MODULE with this code (and replace with your stuff..):

```
{
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "<YOUR-MODULE>\\": "src/"
      },
      "classmap": [
        "src/Command/"
      ]
    },
    "config": {
      "preferred-install": "dist",
      "prepend-autoloader": false
    },
    "type": "prestashop-module",
    "author": "<AUTHOR>",
    "license": "<LICENSE>"
  }
```

3. Connect via ssh, and cd into your module root
4. run `composer dump-autoload -o --no-dev`
5. Test your command by `<ps-root>/bin/console your-module:command`